# Does treatment with one triazole give resistance to all other triazoles?

Tags: medications, resistance, fungal-infection

Let's say a patient is treated with a triazole (e.g. Itraconazole) for an oral thrush infection and the fungus acquires resistance to it, then is that resistance against other triazoles too (e.g. Fluconazole) ? Or can Fluconazole (in this example) be used to treat the infection?

Any related medical papers or guidelines talking about the same will be appreciated. I tried searching for this but most papers talk about resistance w.r.t to a single triazole for a specific fungal species.

Edit: E.g. papers I found -

- https://thecandidadiet.com/wp-content/uploads/research/112.pdf
- https://journals.asm.org/doi/pdf/10.1128/aac.39.1.1
- https://tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2147/IDR.S118892

Comment: Try searching for triazole+resistance+multidrug on scholar.google.com. Plenty of info there, and prior research is a requirement here so have a look and edit in what you find that seems relevant.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I did search for it before asking the question and as I note in the question, all the papers I find talk about resistance w.r.t. a single azole or a specific fungal species (e.g. https://www.thecandidadiet.com/wp-content/uploads/research/112.pdf , https://journals.asm.org/doi/pdf/10.1128/aac.39.1.1 , https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.2147/IDR.S118892)